# LEGO Technic #42082 - Rough Terrain Crane: Loose Feet

Tags: technic, sets, design

LEGO Technic crane set #42082. Putting the feet on now,  are they supposed to click in somehow? Also, my feet don’t seem to touch the ground. I’m worried I messed up somewhere a long time ago. Help please!

Answer (score 9):

Everything's going according to plan.  Check out *Youtuber Sariel's* review on your set ***[HERE](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FTrlyFYOoes)***.

At about 26mins in, he addresses your concern.  He notes the looseness of the feet when fully deployed, and says there are 4 pads stored in a compartment over the front axle. Just build on.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I absolutely love this question and answer. Wish I had more upvotes to give